# How to run a disassembled code 6502?

Tags: 6502, commodore

I have to program in assembly the 6502.
I was forced to use the emulator Vice 128 
I was told that the Commodore 128 is compatible with the instructions of 6502
I am a novice and I was made a practical demonstration but I did not understand anything.
There was an interface of 80 columns which passed with a command (which one?)
The instructions in machine language or assembly (the program)
were entered directly on this matrix of 80 columns.
Also the data are entered in this matrix.
So is this matrix  the memory? Each line represents what?
I was told that this is disassembled code 6502. But I do not know what it means
I'm very confused

I want to run this simple program that
 performs the sum of two numbers.
The two numbers are stored in the first page to the word zero and to the word one. I want to store the result in the second word of the first page.
I imagined that the first line contains 80 words. Is that right?
So I put here the data in hexadecimal (3 and 2).

```
    $03 $02
    LDA $00
    ADC $01
    STA $02
```

But I have a syntax error.
I hope someone can help me because it escapes me how things work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A full discussion of how to run a 6502 assembler or alternatively how to enter the op-codes directly into memory is far too extensive for this site.

Comment: In its current form, your question touches on a lot of very basic concepts and is incredibly broad. I recommend starting off with a basic tutorial on 6502 assembly using the Commodore 64 (as it's a more popular machine and resources for it are more readily found).

Comment: There is some guide that explains how to do? The arguments are old and I could not find anything. I was forced to program in this way with the program directly into memory but I have an overview. I'd need someone or some guide that tells me how to proceed. It is not the assembly the problem but the "configuration"

Comment: I agree with the comments that this question is too broad, but I'd like to give some pointers. First, the 128 has two possible displays: a 40-column one and an 80-column one. In Vice they should both show up simultaneously, but the cursor is only in one at a time. To switch to the 80-column screen, type `graphic 5` from BASIC (when the machine boots you are in BASIC). You were most likely in the **machine language monitor**, which is accessed using the `monitor` command from BASIC. You probably saw a **disassembly** (in the ML monitor) of some section of memory.

Comment: Continuing: You would have entered data and instructions in the monitor also. http://www.commodore.ca/manuals/128_system_guide/app-j.htm is a guide to the monitor. On a more 6502-related note, please note that the 64 and 128's CPUs are not exactly 6502s; they are derived from Commodore's own 6510. The 6510 does not allow you to store bytes in locations 0 or 1 without bad things happening, the way a plain 6502 does.

Answer (score 3):

Fir'st, in 6502, we use we deal with bytes, not words. (it's an 8 bit architecture)

You don't mention which macro assembler you are using, but I assume that its trying to interpret $03 as an op code, not data.  I looked up two options
in ca65 you can use

```
 .BYTE $03 $02
```

in dasm you use

```
 HEX 03 02
```

In addition, 6502 has no concept of 80 anything (words, lines whatever).  The only 80 I can think of is the old terminals that had 80 columns.  I don't see how this is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

> How to run a disassembled code 6502?

You have to *assemble* back the code.

Each 6502 instruction stands for 1, 2, or 3 bytes, the first is called the *opcode*, the optional second or third is the data used by the instruction (the *operand*).

You need a program to translate the instruction mnemonics to bytes.  There were many such programs on the Commodore.

The Commodore 128 had a [built-in monitor](http://www.commodore.ca/manuals/128_system_guide/app-j.htm) that let you enter instructions to assemble directly.  You can enter it by typing `MONITOR` at the BASIC prompt.  You would need to first set the address, then use "assemble" commands.  Then use the "go" command at the starting address to run it.  Use BASIC POKE command to set locations containing data, before you enter the monitor.  The address `0B00` is a good address to use as it's the tape buffer which is unused except during tape I/O.

Good luck.